# Find specific DbContext, when handling a SqlExcpetion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I want to create an Exception Filter:

```
public class BigTouchExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var sqlException = filterContext.Exception as SqlException;
        if (sqlException == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Todo: Handle when it is thrown by `BigTouchContext`
    }
}
```

I have two different DbContexts: `MainContext:DbContext`, and `BigTouchContext:DbContext`. I want to detect in my ExceptionFilter, if the Error is thrown by `BigTouchContext` (Which are actualy multiple tenants).

Is it possible to override the `DbContext` in some way, that it transmits the context type via a custom exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not really find a way to get the DBContext from the assosciated exception, but I can propose a workaround

1. Catch the [DbUpdateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) in your filter.
2. Now in this exception, you can find the entities that failed by accessing the `DbUpdateException.Entries` **Property**
3. Create two lists of entities in the filter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187848/get-list-of-entity-models-in-dbcontext-entity-framework-core-2-1)

```
    var entityTypes = db.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(t => t.ClrType).ToList();
```

4. Get the first entry that failed from step two, and use the `GetType()` method it exposes to search the types from the two lists. The first one that's got it, is your DBContext of choice.

I have not tried that out, but it looks to me like it's going to work.

Unfortunately, DBContext throws one of the following [Check MSDN here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads). `SQL exception` for connectivity issues is not related to DBContext and thus, can't be assosciated to one.

You could maybe correlate by the server [SQL Exception get server name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.server?view=netframework-4.8) which could also be in the [DBContext connection string](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/45322282/how-to-get-connectionstring-from-ef-core-2-0-dbcontext)

Comment: Thx, but the problem is, I get only a `SqlException`, when for example the database is not available, but no `DbUpdateException`.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Very interesting question. Kudos to you.